# Build Failed java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, ant, build

I am facing this issue while building my build.xml.

```
BUILD FAILED
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:94)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.module.DefaultJarArchive.<init>(DefaultJarArchive.
java:75)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.module.DefaultJarArchive.<init>(DefaultJarArchive.
java:56)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.module.webapp.DefaultWarArchive.<init>(DefaultWarA
rchive.java:69)
    at org.apache.cactus.integration.ant.CactifyWarTask.addJarWithClass(Cact
ifyWarTask.java:652)
    at org.apache.cactus.integration.ant.CactifyWarTask.addCactusJars(Cactif
yWarTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.cactus.integration.ant.CactifyWarTask.execute(CactifyWarTa
sk.java:519)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:62)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
```

Answer (score 57):

It sounds like you need to launch your JVM with a larger memory limit. Try something like (if you're using Bourne shell):

```
export ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1g
ant
```

or, if you use `cmd` under Windows:

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1g
ant
```

Above, the `1g` means 1 GB. You can tweak that to whatever you like; for example, if you want to use 1.5 GB, you can use `-Xmx1536m`.

Comment: Where should i add set ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1g ant is it in ant script file??

Comment: Run that command before you type `ant`. I am assuming that you're running `ant` from the command line. If you're running ant from an IDE, your IDE should provide you a way to pass Java options.

Comment: awesome ... thanks a lot. but is there a way to set it like permanently?

Comment: You can set it permanently if you set it as an environment variable. So add the environment variable in the standard editor under windows (or try www.rapidee.com), or simply add the `export` line in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` under linux and mac.

Answer (score 13):

*(For < Java 8, permgen doesn't apply to Java 8 and up)*

For benefit of those who got a similar trace with the word "PermGen" in the Error message,

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Increasing the perm-gean space in ANT_OPTS (preferably, though not necessarily along with the Max heap size) should solve the issue

example

```
export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

Adjust the numbers as per your your need.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

If 'javac' task is used with fork option then , javac will run in his own process and memory should be directly assigned to the javac using 'memoryinitialsize' and 'memorymaximumsize':

```
javac   srcdir="${src}"
            destdir="${classes}"
            source="1.6"
            debug="true"
            fork="true"
            deprecation="off"
            memoryinitialsize="512m"
            memorymaximumsize="1024m"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ANT_OPTS to next higher level in dx.bat file.which is  located \build-tools\versions\dx.bat.
set defaultXmx=-Xmx2048M I set it to 2GB.