# Sonar analysis gives out of memory error, should I increase JVM heap space of Ant or Sonar server?

Tags: ant, jvm, jenkins, sonarqube, heap-memory

I am analysing a large project in Sonar and get the following error:

```
[sonar:sonar] 03:55:39.511 INFO  p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Execute decorators...

BUILD FAILED
[...]
[...] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.sonar.batch.index.MeasurePersister.model(MeasurePersister.java:127)
at org.sonar.batch.index.MeasurePersister.getMeasuresToSave(MeasurePersister.java:117)
at org.sonar.batch.index.MeasurePersister.dump(MeasurePersister.java:70)
at org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultPersistenceManager.dump(DefaultPersistenceManager.java:63)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:95)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:139)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:131)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:121)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:121)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:104)
at org.sonar.ant.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.delegateExecution(SonarTask.java:244)
at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:193)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
```

Should I increase the java heap space of the running Sonar server, or the Ant target executing the Sonar job?

Comment: I am using Jenkins to execute the Ant target (Sonar)

Comment: Oh, OK, that's the possibility I left out...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you can see from the stack trace, the Ant starts the Sonar analysis, so you should increase the heap space for the VM the Ant runs in.

This is a very similar question BTW: [How to increase Sonar Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746292/how-to-increase-sonar-java-heap-size)

**For command line Ant usage**

Quote from the answer by Mark O'Connor on the other question:

> The Sonar ANT task executes as part of ANT so you need to set the JVM heap using the standard ANT environment parameter. For example:
>
> export ANT_OPTS=-Xmx256m

Remarks:

- this is for Linux, for Windows, use the `set` command
- this is strictly for the heap space. for `Permgen`, use `-XX:MaxPermSize=<desired amount>`

This is an even more similar question: [Build Failed java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494909/build-failed-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)

**For Eclipse IDE**

Quote from the article http://soenkerohde.com/2008/06/change-eclipse-ant-settings-when-you-run-out-of-memory/

> - In Eclipse open menu: **Run**->**External Tools**->**Open External Tools Dialog**…
> - Select the build script you want to change on the left
> - Select the **JRE** tab on the right
> - Set the following as **VM arguments**: -Xms768m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

**For IntelliJ Idea**

This forum thread is useful: [ANT build java heap space](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5301721;jsessionid=2A7811535B033B16E553237B44281ED4)

Quote from the answers:

> Please make sure that you increased heap in a correct place. You need to click 'Properties' button in **IDEA's Ant tool window** and edit **'Maximum heap size (Mb)'** field there.

Also, from the IntelliJ Idea page: [Increasing Memory Heap](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/increasing-memory-heap.html)

Quote from the article:

> The memory heap of the build process is independent of IntelliJ IDEA memory heap, and is released after the build process is complete.
>
> To increase a memory heap:
>   Open the **Build File Properties** dialog box. 
>   In the **Maximum heap size** field, type the required amount of memory.

**For Jenkins Continuous Integration and Ant build**

This question is useful : [How to use the `Java Options` in jenkins ant build tool to set ANT_OPTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401002/how-to-use-the-java-options-in-jenkins-ant-build-tool-to-set-ant-opts)

Quote from the answer:

> Set the JAVA OPTIONS as -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m only without the ANT_OPTS=

For **Maven builds**, this article is of use: [How to increase maven heapspace in hudson builds](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/how-to-increase-maven-heapspace-in-hudson-builds-696.html)

> 1. Navigate to your hudson job,
> 2. click **Configure**,
> 3. scroll down to the **Build section**, and
> 4. click the **Advanced** button.
> 5. Enter this into **MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m**

Comment: what is for mac..?