# SonarQube in Azure Pipeline - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to sonarqube to a build pipeline in Azure Devops. In the SonarQube publish step a receive the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:166)
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(Hex.java:161)
at org.sonar.core.hash.SourceLinesHashesComputer.computeHash(SourceLinesHashesComputer.java:63)
at org.sonar.core.hash.SourceLinesHashesComputer.addLine(SourceLinesHashesComputer.java:51)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.source.ComputeFileSourceData.read(ComputeFileSourceData.java:54)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.source.ComputeFileSourceData.compute(ComputeFileSourceData.java:48)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.step.PersistFileSourcesStep$FileSourceVisitor.visitFile(PersistFileSourcesStep.java:120)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitNode(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:79)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:51)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:39)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitChildren(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:98)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:54)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:39)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitChildren(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:98)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:54)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:39)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.step.PersistFileSourcesStep.execute(PersistFileSourcesStep.java:89)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52)
at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:73)
at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:134)
at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.findAndProcessTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:97)
at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$$Lambda$739/1000704267.get(Unknown Source)
at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.withCustomizedThreadName(CeWorkerImpl.java:81)
at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:73)
at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:43)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
```

I tried setting the `SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS` as suggested here: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-error-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded/12624/2 (I added it to the pipeline as environment variable) but this didn't work. Even with a even bigger size.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you running Sonar using Maven or ANT task? If you were, You should set  MAVEN_OPTS/ANT_OPTS envrionment variable. Please check out below answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you ran Sonar using Maven or ANT task. Setting the SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS environment variable probably would not work.

Since Maven/ANT task will execute run Sonar analysis, so you need to set the JVM heap space for Maven/Ant.

For Maven: You should set `MAVEN_OPTS` envrionment variable. You can trt adding it to pipeline as environment variable.

Or you can change the MAVEN_OPTS value under **Advanced** setting of Maven task. see below screenshot:

[image]

For ANT: You should set `ANT_OPTS` envrionment variable(eg. `export ANT_OPTS=-Xmx256m`) by adding it to pipeline as environment variable.

Check this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253218/sonar-analysis-gives-out-of-memory-error-should-i-increase-jvm-heap-space-of-an?rq=1) for more information.